# Why Thread.sleep(200000) is not waiting my script up to that amount of time?)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, thread-sleep

Myy application is bit slow during that step and I need to wait for all elements to be loaded for 2 minutes so I have given Thread.sleep(200000) but the script is not waiting that long and it is giving me
UnreachableBrowserException and shows Error Connecting with remote browser. It may have died.

I am using Selenium 4 alpha version and ChromeDriver also 4 version. Please help. Demo Code below:

```
@And("user clicks on Go button and waits for the members to display")
public void user_clicks_on_go_andwaits()
{
   memberPage.clickGo();
   Thread.sleep(200000);
   // after this step a list of element displays and I need to select one in the below step
}

@And("user selects {int} member")
public void select_member(int memberId)
{
  memberPage.selectMember(memberId);
  //selectMember method is defined in the page object.
}
```

Comment: First of all, [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) takes a time in milliseconds.  2 minutes is 120000 milliseconds, but you typed in 200000 (3 minutes and 20 seconds).  Second of all, I think we're gonna need to see some code in order to help you here.  Please read the [mre] page.

Comment: yes correct I have given some more time as sometime application takes more than 2 minutes also. I cannot share the code as it is project specific.

Comment: I want my script to wait upto the time specified in Thread.sleep but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you read the [mre] page that I linked?  If not, please do, in full.  If you follow the steps on that page, there should be absolutely no project specific code in what you are posting.  You might even solve your own issue before you ever get to posting it.

Comment: We don't care about your _exact_ code, you just need to show _demonstrator_ code that shows this problem off  in a way that we can run, and go "yes, you're right, this is not doing what one would expect", because without code all we can say is "if you did it right, it works fine, and you're not showing any proof that you didn't do it right". So without code, there is no problem for us to help you solve.

Comment: explained the demo code now.

Comment: @NirajSingh - UnreachableBrowserException - This is not related to wait but the driver object is not instantiated to the webdriver browser instance or in your code at some point, the object is getting destroyed.  Please check that and it will help you solve it.

Comment: @vishalgada how to identify in which step driver object is getting destroyed because all previous steps runs fine. When it reaches this step then it fails.

Comment: 3+ minutes is an unusually large wait time. You would be better to run a loop that sleep 1 second and exits after load has completed, failing if the total wait time is "too large".

Comment: @NirajSingh Can you please check if for this method "memberPage.clickGo();"  the execution is successful?

Comment: @vishalgada yes clickGo executes fine but after clicking it a list should display. While loading the list it takes more time and once the list is displayed then scripts break and could not do next steps.

Comment: You can use fluent wait instead of thread.sleep. did you try that?

Comment: I'd assume the driver timeouts during one of the previous thread.sleeps somewhere else in the code, and you only notice it when trying to `clickGo`, which throws exception. When they recommend to use WebDriver wait - they mean use it all the way, not just in the problematic method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dont use thred in selenium automation (That is not good practice) Please use webdriver wait in selenium 

Thread sleep force your automation program 

create method for wait and use anywhere in your program 

**//Following code is method of wait** 

    private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator,int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }
//If you want wait for particular element you can use that wait method which you are written in program

**waitForElement(By.id(""),20);**  
//Here 20 is in milliseconds and you can use any web element to wait with any locators
```

Comment: I have tried webdriver wait as well but still the scripts fails when the page is loaded. Does it has something to do with more scenarios steps?

Comment: Webdriver wait is good practice for wait in selenium